# Projection that merges two streams in eventstore

Tags: projection, eventstoredb

I am trying to create the simplest projection using `fromStreams`, the code saves fine, but the stream `mergeStream0` does not exist

```
var create = function () {
    fromStreams(['storeIdStream7', 'storeIdStream'])
         .when(function(state,event) { 
             emit('mergeStream0', 'mergeType', '123')
     return null; 
  });
};
create()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that run projections ALL has been called on your event store

When using the embedded client the options is as follows

```
var nodeBuilder = EmbeddedVNodeBuilder.AsSingleNode()
    .OnDefaultEndpoints()
    .RunInMemory()
    .RunProjections(EventStore.Common.Options.ProjectionType.All, 1);
```

When starting it on a server you need to include this in your `eventstore.conf`

```
RunProjections: All
ClusterSize: 1
ExtIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Also your projection will only display the links to the original streams, you can also use `linkTo(state, event);` to link to the actual data so it comes back within the projection. But if you omit that, you can use the client and set `resolveLinkTos` to `true`